# Calling MySql stored procedure with MySql C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I have the following table in my database :

```
CREATE TABLE Alita.Cache (
ID              INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Created         DATETIME        NOT NULL,
Modified        DATETIME        NOT NULL,
ProcessState    TINYINT         NOT NULL,
Link            VARCHAR(4000)   CHARSET utf8,
Content         VARCHAR(4000)   CHARSET utf8,

CONSTRAINT PK_CACHE_ID    PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

To add a row in this table I created the following stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Alita.usp_AddCache //
CREATE PROCEDURE Alita.usp_AddCache (
    IN  _link    VARCHAR(4000) CHARSET utf8,
    IN  _content VARCHAR(4000) CHARSET utf8,
    OUT _linkId  INT
 )
PROC_START : BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

SET @id := NULL;
SELECT @id := Id FROM Alita.Cache WHERE Link = _link;
SET _linkId := @id;

IF @id IS NULL THEN 
    INSERT INTO Alita.Cache VALUES(0, NOW(), NOW(), 0, _link, _content);
    SELECT @id := Id FROM Alita.Cache WHERE Link = _link;
    SET _linkId := @id;
    LEAVE PROC_START;
END IF;

UPDATE Alita.Cache 
SET Content = _content, 
    Modified = NOW(), 
    ProcessState = 0 
    WHERE Id = @id AND ProcessState = 2;

COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I try to call this stored procedure from MySql C++ Connector. I wrapped all the database interaction code in a class called ***alita_db***. I used [this tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-tutorials-stored-routines-prepared-statement-out-parameter.html) from MySQL documentation.
The following snippet is the initialization of connection :

```
alita::alita_db::alita_db(const alita::db_connection_info& db_connection_info)
{
    if(db_connection_info._host.empty())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Host.");

    if(db_connection_info._username.empty())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Username.");

    if(db_connection_info._password.empty())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Password.");

    if(db_connection_info._scheme.empty())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Scheme.");

    this->_log = db_connection_info._log;
    this->driver = get_driver_instance();
    this->connection = this->driver->connect(
        db_connection_info._host,
        db_connection_info._username,
        db_connection_info._password);

    this->connection->setSchema(db_connection_info._scheme);  
    this->connection->setAutoCommit(false);
}
```

After initialization I try to execute the call ***usp_AddCache***. The following one is the call snippet using MySql C++ connector APIs.

```
    std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt;
    std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstmt;
    std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res;

    stmt.reset(this->connection->createStatement());
    pstmt.reset(this->connection->prepareStatement("CALL usp_AddCache(?, ?, @_linkId)"));

    pstmt->setString(1, std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>().to_bytes(link));
    pstmt->setString(2, std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>().to_bytes(content));

    pstmt->execute();
```

The code executes successfully without any exception and the auto increment ID counter is changed. Nevertheless, when I query the data with mysql CLI, I get an empty set. 
I am trying to understand why the insert actually fails. 
My question is how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Looks like you are not committing the call. try to change 

    this->connection->setAutoCommit(true);

and re-run.

Comment: @özkanpakdil I understand what you said, but why do I need auto commit if the code of the procedure is already in transaction as you can see? However, I changed the code as you had suggested, but it didn't work either. The procedure actually started to insert a record, when I removed the transaction statement from the code, and set auto commit option.

Comment: I dont know mysql c++ connector much. but this kind of problems appears because of transaction management. looks to me it was not committing properly.